# create or copy document in sharepoint using client object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, java-api

I want the user to press a button and this creates or copies documents (Excel) into a document library on the same sharepoint site. There are many examples showing how to do this for a list but how can it be achieved for documents?

I've looked at SPFile.CopyTo method but dont know how to use it.

So the source file would have a number of destination files and the name and column data would be altered at time of creation. Looking for a client side javascript solution.

Hope someone can assist.

Thanks

Comment: This is not Javascript, but it's ready and free solution https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Module-for-5ecbbcf0. Just use the Copy-SPOFile cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks but It needs to be code as I need to perform other activities.